# Fizban’s Platinum Shield On a Giant Creature

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm wondering how casting *Fizban’s Platinum Shield* on a massive creature, such as a Spelljammer Ship or similarly large creature alters the effects of the spell.

> You create a field of silvery light that surrounds a creature of your choice within range (you can choose yourself). The field sheds dim light out to 5 feet. While surrounded by the field, a creature gains the following benefits: [...]
> As a bonus action on subsequent turns, you can move the field to another creature within 60 feet of the field.

The range is 60 feet, so it might be that some of the creature is outside the range of the spell. The partial coverage rule in the DMG does not seem to apply. Would only the area covered by the spell be covered given their size, or does the fact that part of the creature is within range mean the whole thing is?

Comment: Hi aslonim.  I have closed this question as I believe it is a duplicate of the question to which I have linked.  That's ok, because the additional listing helps people find the other question when they search!  There is a minor difference in that the other question is about an area of effect spell and yours targets 'a creature', but I think the conclusions are the same.  Please read the linked question.  If it does not answer _your_ question, let us know why and we will work with you to reopen this question.

Comment: In the meantime, welcome!  When you have a chance please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the topics available at the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help).  Happy to have you here.